# Как получить нужный id из запроса?

Tags: php, mysql

Сделал я значит поиск, но id выводиться только из таблицы `events`, а мне нужно еще получать id из таблицы `blog` . И сделать условие, для передачи ссылки нужного id.

Вот, что наделал

```
$query = trim($_GET['search']);
$query_date = $_GET['search_date'];
$query = htmlspecialchars($query);
$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$query);
$min_length = 3;
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 
    $search_query = "SELECT `id`,`title`,`add_event` FROM `events` WHERE `title` LIKE '%$query%' AND `add_event` LIKE '%$query_date%' UNION SELECT `id`,`title_post`,`date_post` FROM `blog` WHERE `title_post` LIKE '%$query%' AND `date_post` LIKE '%$query_date%'";
    $raw_results = mysqli_query($conn,$search_query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
        while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)){?>
            <div class="result_seart_be">
                Ивент - <a href="../pages/big_events?event=<?php echo $results['id']; ?>"><?php echo $results['title']; ?></a><span>Дата публикации - <?php echo $results['add_event']; ?></span>
                // тут условие
                Статья- <a href="../pages/big_events?big_blog=<?php echo $results['id']; ?>"><?php echo $results['title_post']; ?></a><span>Дата публикации - <?php echo $results['date_post']; ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php } 
    } else{ ?>
        <h5>Ничего не найдено...</h5>
    <?php }  
} else { ?>
<br><h4 id="alerter">Введите минимум <?php echo $min_length ?> символа!</h4>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Запрос надо сделать таким:

```
$search_query = "SELECT `id`,`title`,`add_event`, 'article' as subj   
FROM `events`   
WHERE `title` LIKE '%$query%' AND `add_event` LIKE '%$query_date%'   
UNION   
SELECT `id`,`title_post` as title,`date_post` as add_event, 'blog' as subj  
FROM `blog`   
WHERE `title_post` LIKE '%$query%' AND `date_post` LIKE '%$query_date%'";
```

И условие можно цеплять к полю subj

Comment: А как именно привязать?Брать subj и например поле title или как?